# jQuery clean text in TR Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, html-table

How to clear all text that appears in a TR table ?

Here is my table:

[image: here is my table]

Below is my script -  I put text in the TR

```
$('#approve_do-table').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {

  var html;
  if ($('#approve_do-table #do-show tr').length === 1) {
    html = '<tr id="no-data"><th style="text-align:center;" class="table-conf even" colspan="5">No data found</th></tr>';
  }
  $('#approve_do-table > tbody').html(html);

  var $this = this;
  var id = $(this).attr('id'),
     latest_no = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').text(),
     part_name = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text(),
     req       = $(this).children('td:eq(2)').text(),
     price     = $(this).children('td:eq(3)').text(),
     amount    = $(this).children('td:eq(4)').text(),
     part_id   = $(this).data('part_id');

  rows_selected.push(this);
  ids_selected.push(id);
  arrPartIds.push(part_id);

  loc = id.replace('part_do', '');
  loctab = $.inArray(id, ids_selected);
  locP = loctab+1;

  $('#part_doDest-table tr:eq('+locP+') td:eq(0)').html(latest_no);
  $('#part_doDest-table tr:eq('+locP+') td:eq(1)').html(part_name+'<i class="fa fa-times eks" aria-hidden="true" id="'+id+'"></i>');
  $('#part_doDest-table tr:eq('+locP+') td:eq(2)').attr({'contenteditable': false, 'id': 'edit'+loc, 'oninput': 'inputFunc("'+loc+'")','onblur':'removeTooltips("'+loc+'")', 'placeholder': '0'}).html(req);

  $('#part_doDest-table tr:eq('+locP+') td:eq(3)').attr('id', 'price'+loc).html(price);
  $('#part_doDest-table tr:eq('+locP+') td:eq(4)').attr('id','amount'+loc).html(amount);
  $(this).remove();
  sumSubtotal2();
});
```

And here is my script to clear the array, but the text on the element isn't cleared.

```
$('.cancel_btn').click(function(event) {

  alert(1);
  ids_selected    = [];
  rows_selected   = [];

  $('#part_doDest-table').closest('tr').remove();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#approve_do-table tbody tr').remove()` ? That should remove ALL row in `tbody`... (I'm not sure that is what you mean, but that's all I understand for now.)

Comment: yes, but there is removing TR element , i want set empty the TR element sir like html(""); but here also not working , also i was tried text("");

Answer (score 0):

> I want set empty the TR element sir, like html("");

To "empty" some table rows... Without removing them, you have to empty the cells (which are `td`).

Try this:

```
$('#approve_do-table tbody td').empty()
```